# Why won't my simple post request work when testing in Postman in terms of sending file to API?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

I have two separate code bases.  React.js on the frontend and Laravel for backend.  In my backend code, I'm trying to send a file to the API.  However, I keep getting `upload_file_not_found`.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Again, the codebases are completely separated so I think that's where my issue lies with this but I'm not sure.  I've hit a wall with this.

Even if I get rid of `Bearer ....`, it still gives the same error.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

[image]

frontend code:

```
<form action={this.state.url} method="post" encType="multipart/form-data" className="upload" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" className="fileToUpload" onChange={this.uploadHandler}/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" className="submitBtn"/>
</form>
```

backend code:

```
class FileUploadController extends Controller {
    public function uploadTest(Request $request) {

        if(!$request->hasFile('fileToUpload')) {
            return response()->json(['upload_file_not_found'], 400);
        }
        $file = $request->file('fileToUpload');
        if(!$file->isValid()) {
            return response()->json(['invalid_file_upload'], 400);
        }
        $path = public_path() . '/uploads/images/store/';
        $file->move($path, $file->getClientOriginalName());
        return response()->json(compact('path'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you dd the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a complete guess because it's really to hard to say without playing around with that myself, but if that function is expecting the Request object  to have a key called 'fileToUpload', you need to provide that. With an associated image. You're making a post request from postman, but you have an empty key beside the image name, is that not what the function is checking to see if it's set, should you not put fileToUpload in the key and then the value stay as it is "unnamed (1) .jpg", also maybe try upload an image with a shorter name and no spaces so it's easier to be sure you have it in correctly.

Comment: That was it!!! I forgot the `fileToUpload` as the key.  thank you!!!!!!